# C#, Visual studio project installer; All assembly (.dll files) are put in the same folder as the installation folder

Tags: c#, file, installation, dll

So; I installed xunit and suddenly using microsoft visual studio project installer to install my solution.. I compile and install.. now I have like 20+ .dll files in my installation folder.

Is it possible to move these into a separate folder somehow?

I tried to create a bin folder under "application folder" and put the .dll there; but then the program does not work and it is not linked anymore.

How can I fix this?

So I want to, using microsoft visual studio installer project extension, put the assembly output that my project needs in a bin folder.

Comment: Which project are you publishing? Is xunit really a library you're using in the project you're publishing?

Comment: I'm trying to publish an entire solution that contains 2 projects; and they both have their own output .exe with the installation. The issue could be worded that; I change the place where it outputs the assembly .dll files; but then the programs can not find them in a bin folder instead.

Comment: Where is xunit being used? That's a unit testing framework. It shouldn't be delivered to the end user.